# Stuck on Recursion Python

Tags: python, recursion

My basic recursion function is like this:

input_string would be in this format = [ [cow pig donkey], 'pig dog']

```
keep_track = []
def recursion(input_string, finding_name):
    list_names = list format
```

[cow pig donkey], [pig], [dog]

```
    for item in list_names:
        if item is A SINGLE WORLD:
```

ie [pig]

```
            if name is finding_name:
                keep_track append name
        else name is A LIST WITH MULTIPLE WORDS:
```

ie [cow pig donkey]

```
            recursion([cow pig donkey], finding_name)
```

[cow], [pig], [donkey]

This is where I'm getting stuck. Since I have a return statement at the end

```
    return keep_track
```

my function is returning multiple times if my recursion is called. I'm not sure how to fix my function so that I only return once.

FUNCTION WITHOUT THE COMMENTS

```
 keep_track = []
 def recursion(input_string, finding_name):
     list_names = basically would do this the first time
     for item in list_names:
         if item is A SINGLE WORLD:
             if name is finding_name:
                 keep_track append name
         else name is A LIST WITH MULTIPLE WORDS:
             recursion(item, finding_name)
     return list_names
```

Comment: Please fix indentation... it's very important to get exactly right in Python, I don't know which lines are part of which clauses!

Comment: What do you want to do with the result of the recursive call? Add it to the list?

Comment: The recursion call would make [cow pig donkey] to [cow], [pig], [donkey]. Then, I could use the single words to compare it to what I want and then add it to the list. I can't use whole sentences and need individual words.

Comment: What is `[cow pig donkey]`? Do you mean `['cow', 'pig', 'donkey']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a mess so it's very difficult to understand what you're trying to ask. An hour later, it's still not clear. I'm going to make a best-guess attempt at answering what appears to be the question.

It seems you've been given a list of strings nested arbitrarily deep. Something like:

```
in_lst = ['horse', 'cow', 'dog', ['pig', 'pig', 'horse'], 'cat', 'sheep']
```

And you want to end up with a list containing all the occurrences of a particular string

```
foo(in_lst, "pig") == ["pig", "pig"]
foo(in_lst, "horse") == ["horse", "horse"]
foo(in_lst, "dog") == ["dog"]
```

The easiest way to do that is probably to flatten the list, then filter (rather than recurse directly).

```
# Python3.3+
def flatten(lst):
    for el in lst:
        try:
            yield from flatten(el)
        except TypeError:
            yield el

# Python3, before 3.3
def flatten(lst):
    accum = []
    for el in lst:
        if hasattr(el, "__iter__") and not isinstance(el, str):
            accum.extend(flatten(el))
        else:
            accum.append(el)
    return accum

# Python2
def flatten(lst): 
    # same as Python3 before 3.3, except replace
    ...
        if hasattr(el, "__iter__") and not isinstance(el, str):
    # with
    ...
        if hasattr(el, "__iter__") and not isinstance(el, basestring):

def find_names(haystack, needle):
    return filter(lambda el: el==needle, flatten(haystack))
    # or return [el for el in flatten(haystack) if el == needle]
```

if you MUST recurse directly for some reason (hint: don't), then try the same method I used when flattening:

```
def find_names(haystack, needle):
    accum = []
    for el in lst:
        if hasattr(el, "__iter__") and not isinstance(el, str):
            accum.extend(find_names(el, needle))
        elif el == needle:
            accum.append(el)
    return accum
```

Although arguably it might be easier to just count.

```
def find_names(haystack, needle):
    return [needle] * sum(1 for el in flatten(haystack) if el==needle)
```

Comment: Sorry for confusing code and you did understand what I wanted to do. I also have to use recursion

Comment: Why do you test for `str` then `basestring`? Shouldn't the latter be sufficient? (Python 2 version)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I don't. The comments say to replace the `str` test with the `basestring` test :)

Comment: @AdamSmith Oh I misread that the first time. Now I understand.